# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xec in position 14: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, scikit-learn

here my error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/dani ibrahim/PycharmProjects/TestPy/Test.py", line 16, in <module>
    load_content=True, encoding='utf-8', shuffle=True, random_state=42)
  File "C:\Users\dani ibrahim\PycharmProjects\TestPy\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\base.py", line 197, in load_files
    data = [d.decode(encoding, decode_error) for d in data]
  File "C:\Users\dani ibrahim\PycharmProjects\TestPy\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\base.py", line 197, in <listcomp>
    data = [d.decode(encoding, decode_error) for d in data]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xec in position 14: invalid continuation byte
```

here my code, how can i fix this?

```
docs_to_train = sklearn.datasets.load_files("/Users/dani ibrahim/PycharmProjects/TestPy/data/",
    description=None, categories=categories,
    load_content=True, encoding='utf-8', shuffle=True, random_state=42)
```

Comment: Sounds like your file isn't UTF-8. What makes you think it is?

Comment: first i use 'latin-1', i got error like this "ValueError: empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stop words", so i change to utf-8

Comment: Are you sure `/Users/dani ibrahim/PycharmProjects/TestPy/data/` is the path of a file ?

Comment: for the datas, i use in folder data, and for the project in the TestPy.
but when i tried to move to folder TestPy, i got the same error

Comment: Just randomly guessing at the encoding could require dozens of tries before you find the right one. If you can `open` the file in binary mode, then `print(f.read(100))` and post the result here (it should look like `b'…'`, with the stuff inside the quotes possibly including a bunch of stuff like `\xec` or `\x00`). Or try running `chardet` or `unicodedamnit` on the file.

Comment: done sir, but i got a new error like this "ValueError: empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stop words" @arbarnert